# Is there a better way to implement a matching algorithm in Pandas/Python?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, simulation

I have two datasets of (lets say travellers) departing and arriving to a bus station. I have data of the time they arrive, the time they depart and some other about the characteristics of their trip (company name etc) like this:

**Arrivals**

```
ID, ArrivalTime, CompanyName
1, 10:30, 'EuroBus'
2, 10:30, 'EuroBus'
3, 10:40, 'OverflowTrip'
```

**Departures**

```
ID, DepartureTime, CompanyName
1, 13:30, 'EuroBus'
2, 13:40,' OverflowTrip'
3, 12:10, 'OverflowTrip'
```

And I need to match them more or less like this:

```
for each arrivalPassanger in Arrivals
    possible_Departures <- select_possible_departures( Departures, matching_criteria )
    selected_Departure <- select_departure( Departures, more_specific_matching_criteria )
    arrivalPassanger.departure <- selected_Departure
    Departures.remove( selected_Departure )
```

As I was already using Pandas my first approach was

```
    for arrivalPassanger in Arrivals.itertuples():
        #This criteria is going to be more complex
        possible_Departures = Departures[Departures.Time >= (arrivalPassanger .ArrivalTime + MARGIN)]

        if possible_Departures.shape[0] == 0:
            Arrivals.loc[arrivalPassanger .Index, "ID_Departure"] = "Unmatched"
        else:
            #This criteria is going to be more complex, for now i take the first occurrence
            selected_Departure = Departures.iloc[0]
            Arrivals.loc[arrivalPassanger.Index, "ID_Departure"] = selected_Departure.ID
            Departures.drop(selected_Departure.name, inplace=True)
```

For now it works, and since the datasets are no so big (around 20k each one) they don't take too much time, but while I plan to add complexity to the matching criteria and I see that the datasets are going to be larger. Should I take a different approach? There's in Pandas a better way to do this? Should I go for numpy arrays instead? I'm aware that iterate in Pandas is not a recommended option.

PS: I'm not sure if "matching algorithm" is a good name for this in English...

Have a great weekend =)

Comment: Would [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) help?

Comment: It's a great page, thanks. But i can't find a solution usable to this "select and take away from the matching pool" kind of problem. Any idea?

Comment: @Leo Can you be more specific?

Comment: I think the core problem (and the think that prevents me from finding an alternative to iteration) is the fact that for each match I find in 'Departures' i have to drop it, so I don't use it again. Should I use numpy arrays instead of a pandas dataset to improve performance? Is there a function in pandas that can help me? (Other comments about my aproach/code is welcomed)